# Is the Decanter of endless water unlimited?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I have given my party a decanter of endless water (was part of an in game joke, a dwarf was left the amulet of the drunkard and a decanter of endless water to make sure he never was without a drink).

At the time it felt like an innocuous magic item to give but then the campaign took a left turn into the fire plane.

So I wanted to confirm I am letting my party use the tankard correctly, an action and a reaction to say the trigger word and aim the geyser (30 gallons) which does 30 cold damage to a fire elemental (plus the potential of the bludgeoning damage) and, more importantly, can be used over and over again with no limitations?

Is that correct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Using your action and *bonus action*, the Decanter can deal 30 cold damage to a fire elemental each turn.

You’ve mostly got the right idea, except aiming the Decanter’s geyser is a bonus action, not a reaction:

> *As a bonus action* while holding the decanter, you can aim the geyser at a creature you can see within 30 feet of you.

Since the geyser is 30 gallons of water, a fire elemental would take 30 cold damage:

> ***Water Susceptibility.*** For every 5 feet the elemental moves in water, or for every gallon of water splashed on it, it takes 1 cold damage.

There are no limitations to how often you can use the Decanter’s geyser, except the action economy that restricts you to a single bonus action per turn.

Comment: "except the action economy that restricts you to a single bonus action per turn." I believe it is even limited to once per round because "The water stops pouring out at the start of your next turn.". So I believe you could not "free object interaction" pass it around your party for everyone to use.

Comment: @findusl The rules for free object interaction, as well as the Use an Object action, do not affect magic items in any way: if a magic item tells you to use an action/bonus action, that is not the same as a free object interaction/Use an Object action.

Comment: @KogarashiKaito I'm not sure what you mean. I never said that you can use a free object interaction instead of an action. Free object interaction allows you to hand your magic item to your allies who can use their action / bonus action to activate the item again. But this item is active until the start of your next turn, so that probably does not work.

Comment: @findusl But eve then, there's nothing within the magic item's description stating you can't give it another command while it is still pouring water, hence making it so it can't be commanded until it stops pouring water is up to DM's interpretation.

Comment: "You can use an action to ***remove the stopper and*** speak one of three Command words"  Wouldn't the stopper have to be in place and be removed for the Command word to have effect?  If multiple people could use it in one turn, the second person could aim it at a different creature.  It wouldn't make sense for the first creature to take all the damage because some of the water from the first use would still be coming out when it was aimed at the second creature.  Also handing it off could remove the 'aiming' done. The second person would also have to replace the stopper first.

Comment: Are you suggesting that giving it a second command while it's already running would blast a *further* 30 gallons of water out?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat On a technical note, the creature takes all 30 points of damage at once when the water is first poured on it, not over multiple turns, otherwise, it moving on its turn would reduce the damage in the same way you are suggesting that passing the item off to an ally who aims it at a different creature would.